# How to remove extra empty column in end of free jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If zoom level is not 100% and small screen resolution is used, extra empty column appears in end of free jqgrid for some zoom levels.
To reproduce, open

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Andrus-.htm

in Chrome at 67% zoom level in 1024x768 screen resolution:

[image: extra]

For some other grid layouts free column is wider.

How to remove empty column at end ?

In earlier versions it does not occur.

Comment: can you apply your jqgrid properties

Comment: I don't understand this. What to apply?

Comment: Means can you write what is your  jqgrid property

Comment: You can open the page in question, right click on it and select View source. You see whole definition there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in scaling of border of the grid which have 1px. As the result it can exist the difference in width of the grid and the outer div which is less then 1px, but which is still visible.

One can fix the problem by usage `.getBoundingClientRect().width` instead of `jQuery.width` for getting the width of the grid and to setting the same value on different outer divs of jqGrid on every grid or column resizing and on resizing (changing the zoom) of the page. The corresponding code could be the following:

```js
var fineTuningOfWidth = function () {
        var $grid = $("#list"),
            gridWidth = $grid[0].getBoundingClientRect().width.toFixed(2) + "px",
            $gview = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view");
        $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css("width", gridWidth);
        $gview.children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").css("width", gridWidth);
        $gview.css("width", gridWidth);
        $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").css("width", gridWidth);
    };
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    url: "andrus.json",
    colModel: [
        { label: "", name: "_actions", template: "actions" },
        { label: "Nimetus", name: "Nimi", jsonmap: "cell.0" }
    ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
}).bind("jqGridResizeStop", fineTuningOfWidth);
$(window).resize(fineTuningOfWidth);
setTimeout(fineTuningOfWidth, 150); // initial fine tuning of the width
```

See [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Andrus-1.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Are there any plans to fix this in jqgrid source code ?

Comment: @Andrus: If one use the approach then one **have to** adjust the width of all dives inside of `$(window).resize`. If one don't do this the the grid could have unneeded horizontal scrollbar. Moreover one have to make many tests for old web browsers. I'm not sure that I'll change the code soon. I see the problem non-critical. I will look at the problem in the future.